# Intuition for expression of most likely trajectory of an SDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, soft-question, stochastic-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider a stochastic differential equation evolving on $\mathbb R$

\begin{equation}
dx_t = f(x_t)dt + c dw_t ,\quad x_0 = y \in \mathbb R
\end{equation}

where $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, c \in \mathbb R$ and $w_t$ is an $1$-dimensional Wiener process/Brownian motion.

In [eq. 8.6, 1] Dürr and Bach showed that when $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ the most likely trajectory taken by $x_t$ on the time interval $[0,T]$ is the solution to

\begin{equation}
\ddot z_t = f(z_t) f'(z_t) + \frac {c^2} 2 f''(z_t), \quad
z_0 = y, \quad \dot z_T = f(z_T)
\end{equation}

*Note:* In [1] the most likely trajectory is defined as the differentiable path starting at $y$ whose surrounding tube of radius $\epsilon$ in the uniform norm has maximal probability under $x_t$. They show that this is well-defined provided that $\epsilon$ is below some threshold.

I am struggling to get an intuition for this result. Intuitively, one can interpret the SDE as repeatedly adding Gaussian noise to the ODE $dx_t = f(x_t)dt$. (For instance, this is what happens as one integrates the SDE using the Euler-Maruyama scheme). This leads one to think that the most likely path would be given by $\dot z_t = f(z_t), z_0=y$. (I know that this mental picture is inaccurate since it ignores the contribution of the noise to the derivative of the process and hence its influence on the motion.)

**Question:** Is there some intuition as to why the expression for the most likely path of the process makes sense?

**Bonus question:** How about if instead of considering Brownian noise, we considered the same SDE driven by smooth noise (e.g. Brownian motion convolved with a mollifier), would the most likely path still be very different from $\dot z_t = f(z_t)$? I am guessing that, in virtue of the Wong-Zakai theorems, the situation will be analogous to the Brownian case.

[1] Dürr, Bach (1978). The Onsager-Machlup function as Lagrangian for the most probable path of a diffusion process. Communications in Mathematical Physics.

*Addendum:* According to the Stratonovich path integral formalism as presented in [2], the *action* (ie negative log probability) of a path $x= \left\{x_t, t\in [0,T]\right\}$ is (up to an additive constant):

\begin{equation}
-\log p(x \mid x_0=y ) =\int_0^T \frac 1 {2c^2}(\dot{x}_t-f(x_t))^2 +f'(x_t) d t
\end{equation}

If $f'$ is a constant then we can see that the most likely path, ie the path of least action, is simply $\dot z_t = f(z_t), z_0=y$; this is also what we find by solving the equation of Dürr and Bach in this case. In the non-linear case, the non-constant derivative term $f'$ leads to the more complex expression for the most likely path. In particular, if we apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to the action, we recover the second-order ODE of Dürr and Bach (this is how they obtain the most likely path in their paper). Interestingly, we can see that in the limit of small $c$, the contribution of $f'$ to the action will be small wrt $(\dot{x}_t-f(x_t))^2$ and so the most likely path will tend to $\dot z_t = f(z_t), z_0=y$.

[2] Seifert (2012). Stochastic thermodynamics, fluctuation theorems and molecular machines. Reports on Progress in Physics.

Comment: Based on my own background I would want to look at small $c$ before doing anything else...in this setting the probability of the path to fall into a set $A$ morally behaves like $e^{-(1/c) \inf_{z \in A} \int_0^T |\dot{z}_t - f(z_t)|^2 dt}$ (with large deviation theory giving the specifics), which would suggest that the most likely path has $\dot{z}_t=f(z_t)$. Does this statement give that at least as $c \to 0$?

Comment: To put it another way, I would be interested to see a comparison of the solution to $z'=f(z),z(0)=y$ with that of $z''=f(z) f'(z) + c^2 f''(z)/2,z(0)=y,z'(T)=f(z(T))$ for small $c$, for some trial $f$'s.

Comment: @Ian: you mean numerical simulations, right? I haven't been able to get any analytic results for specific functions yet, beyond the fact that trajectories trivially coincide for linear f.

Comment: @Ian: in the statistical physics literature, the probability of a path is formulated slightly differently, with an added derivative term inside the integral. In the limit of small c, one recovers $\dot z_t = f(z_t)$. I added some more details at the end of the post.

Comment: The fact that the trajectories coincide for linear $f$ makes me think that there is something special going on with this final BC even in the nonlinear case, which should be considered part of the intuition. For example with $f(z)=z$, somehow that BC suppresses the decaying exponential. Presumably you would have the same sort of behavior even if $f$ with say $z+\epsilon \sin(z)$ for small enough $\epsilon$.

Comment: What do you mean by BC?

Comment: Boundary condition.

Comment: Oh, is the original SDE interpreted as Ito or Stratonovich? What I said in my first comment assumed Ito.

Comment: c is a constant so the Ito and Stratonovich interpretations coincide

Comment: I guess the question boils down to why that $f'$ term in the action is there, and why the terminal BC is what it is.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the derivative of some increasing function of $|\dot{z}_t-f(z_t)|$, I'd expect that to usually be negative.